# EF Core Table-Per-Hierarchy for class with generic

Tags: c#, oop, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 3.1.15 I manage a model with a generic.  I would like to store the entities in the same table basis Table-Per-Hierarchy approach (TPH pattern).  Below is the model abstracted.  The resulting database creates 1 table for `Part` and descendants with a discriminator (as expected), but instead of 1 table for `BaseComputer` and descendants it creates a separate table for `Computers` and a separate table for `Laptops` (not expected).

```c
namespace EFGetStarted
{
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Laptop> Laptops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseComputer<T> where T : Part
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<T> Parts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Computer : BaseComputer<Part>
    {
        public string ComputerSpecificProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Laptop : BaseComputer<LaptopPart>
    {
        public string LaptopSpecificProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
    }

    public class LaptopPart : Part
    {
        public string LaptopSpecificPartProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried explicitly specifying the entity as TPH:

```c
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseComputer<Part>>()
        .HasDiscriminator()
        .HasValue<Computer>("Computer")
        .HasValue<Laptop>("Laptop");
}
```

But this fails with the following message:

> The entity type 'Laptop' cannot inherit from 'BaseComputer' because 'Laptop' is not a descendant of 'BaseComputer'.

Questions: Is it possible for me to design this model in a TPH pattern?  If not, is it because "`Laptop` is not a descendant of `BaseComputer<Part>`"?  And if that's the case, why is not a considered a descendant and what should I change in the class to make it a descendant?

Comment: For now I have refactored it without the generic and putting the `Parts` property on each concrete class with the specific type of `Part`.  I'd still rather have the generic in the abstract base class if possible.